# Get property class giving the property name

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

**What I need**

I have a bunch of classes generated from my data model that inherit from NSManagedObject. I need a way to get, for any of theses classes, a dictionary of a string of a property name as the key, and the string of it's type as the value, for every property name passed in an array.
 Or better, in code:

```
// what I have - generated code
@interface ClassA : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) ClassX *propX;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ClassY *propY;

@end

@implementation ClassA

@dynamic propX;
@dynamic propy;

@end

// what I need
// the method
-(NSDictionary*)dictFromPropNameToPropType:(NSArray*)props {
    //dict being something like @{ @"propX" : @"ClassX", @"propY" : @"ClassY" };
    return dict;
}

// call
dictFromPropNameToPropType(@[@"propX", @"propY"]);
```

The logic of the dictionary creation is on me. I need a way to get the property class name as a string, giving it's name.

**What I've tried**

```
// a instance method of my ClassA
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(propertyNameAsString); // like @"propX"
id object = [self performSelector:selector];
Class class = [object class];
NSString *className = NSStringFromClass(class);
```

and also tried something with `dictionaryWithValuesForKeys`, but it seems to use the same mechanism and result in the same kind of errors.

No succes there. I get the "class not key value coding-compliant" error for the key passed in as `propertyNameAsString`, even thou I have the `propX` property in my ClassA

**What I've researched**

I've looked the Apple tutorials about KVC and KVO, and also the one about the Runtime (to learn something about the @dynamic auto-generated property). But didn't figure it out on my own.

**Edit**

With Martin R's answer, I've got this code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSMutableDictionary new];
NSEntityDescription *selfEntity = [self entity];
NSDictionary *relationshipsByName = selfEntity.relationshipsByName;
for (NSString *relationDescription in relationshipsByName) {
    NSRelationshipDescription *relationshipDescription = relationshipsByName[relationDescription];
    NSEntityDescription *destinationEntity = relationshipDescription.destinationEntity;
    result[relationDescription] = destinationEntity.managedObjectClassName;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have subclasses of `NSManagedObject`, so you can inspect the objects `entity`, which is
a `NSEntityDescription`.

- From the entity description, get the `propertiesByName`, which is
  a dictionary with the property names as key. The values are `NSAttributeDescription`
  or `NSRelationshipDescription` objects.
- `NSAttributeDescription` has a method `attributeValueClassName`, which is the class
  representing the attribute (as a string).
- `NSRelationshipDescription` has a method `destinationEntity` which describes the target
  entity and has a `managedObjectClassName` method.

Comment: It does the trick! Also, I've used the [self entity].relationshipsByName property.
Any hints on how to get the same result with a class method?

Comment: All you need is the NSEntityDescription, which you can create with `[NSEntityDescription entityForName:NSStringFromClass ([self class]) inManagedObjectContext:context]`. - But you need the managed object context, so this works only if you have a global context (in the app delegate or as a shared instance).