# Core Data: How to check if value is compatible with attribute?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm looking for a way to check if an arbitrary value is compatible with a given attribute.

If trying to set a `NSNumber` to `firstName` where a `NSString` is expected, this exception is thrown:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "name"; desired type = NSString; given type = __NSCFNumber;
```

When working with dynamic and possibly bad data, like when receiving `JSON` from a service, I would like to check in runtime the value is compatible or not. Is there any simple and stable way to do this for all combinations of attribute types and values?

Comment: Could you give a more concrete example. Do you get dynamic data at runtime or don't you want to take care of type consistency at compile / design time?

Comment: You can inspect the Core Data entities NSEntityDescription, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23565073/get-property-class-giving-the-property-name.

Comment: @vadian, I get dynamic data at runtime and want to ignore invalid data, instead of crashing. I do want type consistency.

Comment: In case of the number / string example where a string is expected use string interpolation `"\(value)"`

Answer (score 1):

Each Core Data entity is described by an instance `NSEntityDescription`,
which contains all information about the attributes, properties, their
types, etc.

The `entity` property of `NSManagedObject` is a reference to that 
description.

Here is a possible implementation as a "proof of concept".

```
myObject.safeSetValue(value, forKey: key)
```

sets the value (and returns `true`) if the value type is compatible with the entities type, and returns  `false` otherwise.

```
extension NSManagedObject {

    func safeSetValue(value : AnyObject, forKey key : String) -> Bool {

        // Get NSAttributeDescription for key:
        guard let attr = self.entity.attributesByName[key] else {
            return false
        }
        // Get name of the class used to represent the attribute:
        guard let cname = attr.attributeValueClassName else {
            return false
        }
        // Create class object from name:
        guard let cls : AnyClass = NSClassFromString(cname) else {
            return false
        }
        // Check if given value is an instance of a subclass:
        if !value.isKindOfClass(cls) {
            return false
        }
        // Finally: Set value for key:
        self.setValue(value, forKey: key)
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Swift's functionality as follows

`let desiredVariable = responseData["key"] as? String ?? ""`

This'll check if the returned data is of type String. If not, then it'll initialise with empty string.